# How was I able to lock the keys in my 2014 Honda Pilot?

Tags: honda, locks

I had thought this was virtually impossible. I have tried numerous times to lock the doors of my 2014 Honda Pilot while one door was open, It does not matter which door, if you use the key fob or the door lock button, the locks don't activate. Normally everyone is getting out and if you try unsuccessfully to lock the car, before the last door is closed...

Yesterday I was at the lake, tossed my keys on the floor of the car (*so they would not get wet*) pushed the lock button on the drivers door and closed the door, all in one nice fluid motion. As I looked at my keys laying on the floor as the door shut, I was think I am so glad this is Honda so I can't lock myself out.  But when I grabbed the handle to open the door, it was locked!

I have tried a to recreate and have not been able to. If you push the lock button with the door open, it does not lock.

How could this happen?

Comment: I can only relate my experience of a *really* old Honda Accord; you can't normally lock the drivers door unless it is closed, but if you pull the inside door handle slightly, you can then push the lock button. Close the door, and it's locked. I do it all the time, because that car does not have remote locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to lock the key in the car because I failed to understand the door locks. Further testing indicates that the doors always lock when the button on the drivers door is pushed, without regard to any other considerations.

Further research required to determine if this is factory setting that can be changed.  Have I mis-remembered the original settings or accidently modified them?